# How edit element.style in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

I am trying to edit a drop down menu which I defined recently in function.php file in WordPress.

So I want to show two menu in header of WordPress like this :

[image]

So I want to increase the width of menu and want to make this like this :

[image: Image2]

So if I am trying to put code in a div and trying to increase width of div then the whole thing is increasing and if I am trying to inspect element then its showing this :

```
element.style {
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
```

So how I can modify element.style when its not define anywhere in stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have added width to the global select element of theme style sheet.

```
select{padding: 6px 8px; border-radius: 0; outline: 0;width:209px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase css priority by nested class.

Demo:-

```
<span><p>hair</p></span>
```

CSS:-

```
p{color:red;}  
span p{color :blue;}
```

The above demo will display blue colour text.

Answer (score 0):

Element style define in main source code, like this:

```
<select class="btn fixed" style="width:250px"></select>
```

You should overwrite some code to CSS file.

```
.btn.fixed[style] {width: 800px !important;}
```

Like when style a 'placeholder' attribute in 'input' element.